# How to fix the recovery mode error?

Tags: rooting, root-access, recovery-mode

I am trying to root my Samsung Galaxy Ch@t GT-B5330 (4.1.2) following [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZ9P5cVS35w). I have reached the point when I am intended to use the recovery mode menu (that is reached by holding volume-up when turning the phone on) but here am I stuck: whatever I choose gives me the error icon

[image]

I am still able to boot the phone the normal way (though it has became a little bit slower than it was before flashing and starts Firefox on itself occasionally).

How do I finish the rooting process?

Answer (score 0):

Hit the Volume Up
 and Power Buttons simultaneously ( Do not hold the keys).

Comment: Perhaps you are right but I had no chance to try it - I have reflashed the whole system already which has given me a different (and working) recovery screen.

Comment: By the way I have tried holding both keys (the same way like holding down for flashing ir up for recovery) with no result.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to Flash Stock Firmware using Odin, but remember to backup your data first to a SD Card , when you flash the stock firmware , it will fix your recovery mode ...

Once you install Stock the firmware, download and install this software [King Root](https://www.kingoapp.com/android-root/download.htm)

After downloading the Software to your computer , enable **USB Debugging Mode** you can find it in **Developer Options** in your Device.
Then connect your Device to your Computer and the device will be detected by King Root and you just click Start Rooting

**Note**

- You have to install proper drivers required for the Software to detect your phone.
- The best way to install the driver for your Samsung Device is Installing **Samsung Kies**

I hope it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You have to find your ROM according to your model.. below is  the introduction

https://lifehacker.com/how-to-flash-a-rom-to-your-android-phone-30885281